# Tomcat7 out of memory error even after increasing the heap size

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat7, out-of-memory, openmrs

(Not a duplicate, i've searched everywhere) I am using Ubuntu server and Tomcat7 gave a PemGenError out of memory. Then i increased the memory in **setenv.sh** file using  `export CATALINA_OPTS="Xms2048M -Xmx2048M"`. Error disappeared for awhile. But now its appearing again.

1. I am using Tomcat for OpenMRS.
2. Pretty sure it doesn't take that  much memory.
3. I am running OpenMRS in my laptop fine without allocating this much memory.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Not a duplication since every question is about initial error of out of memory.  This happens even after increasing the memory more than enough. I think the increasing worked because the tomcat ran fine for awhile afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have increased the wrong memory pool. When tomcat is out of PermGen-memory increasing the heap won't help. Try `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m` (default is 64m).

As an alternative think about migrating to Java 8 that does not have the PermGen at all. Instead there's metaspace that (in the default settings) would grow indefinitely as long as your machines memory allows.

Comment: Thank you, now only i understood what happened when i added JAVA_OPTS with above mentioned parameters instead of CATALINA_OPTS with heap.

Answer (score 0):

Set the minimum to 1024M and restart tomcat!

Comment: No way of fiddling with `Xms` and `Xmx` will help with an OutOfMemoryError on the PermGen...

Comment: @piet.t Thanks. increase permsize and now works fine